# Flutter How to use Getx controller and change UI with work manager?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, android-workmanager

I'm trying to make reminders with notifications on my app so I have a reminder views screen that I'm getting dependence injection by

```
final ReminderController reminderController = Get.find();
```

I'm creating a reminder notification and the default is active so I've made the work manager class.

```
class WorkServiceManager {
  late String id;
  void init() {
    id = Storage().box.read("reminder_id");
    //final ReminderController reminderController = Get.find();
    Workmanager().initialize(
        actionTask, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
        isInDebugMode:
            false // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
        );
    Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
      id,
      "Show Notification_$id",
      initialDelay: const Duration(seconds: 15),
    );
    log("task registered with ID $id");
  }

  void cancelTask(String id) {
    Workmanager().cancelByUniqueName(id);
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void actionTask() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    LocalNotificationServices.showBasicNotification(
      0,
      "Sch Notification",
      "Body Body",
    );
    await performDatabaseUpdate(taskName);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

Future<void> performDatabaseUpdate(String tasknames) async {
  // Your database update logic goes here
  String s = tasknames.split("_")[1];
  await Get.put(ReminderController()).updateReminderStatus(int.parse(s), false);
  log("Database Updated");
}
```

to run schedule notification and after the notification is done I run an update script into the database to make it off like attaching an image

[image]

and that's my UI screen

```
      SizedBox(
        child: Obx(() {
          if (reminderController.reminders.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: null);
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: reminderController.reminders.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Reminder remind = reminderController.reminders[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(remind.name!),
                  subtitle: Text(remind.describtion!),
                  trailing: Switch(
                    value: remind.reminderactive!,
                    onChanged: (bool newval) async {
                      await reminderController.updateReminderStatus(
                        remind.id!,
                        newval,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        }),
```

and that's my getx controller

```
class ReminderController extends GetxController {
  var reminders = <Reminder>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    fetchReminders();
  }

  Future<void> fetchReminders() async {
    try {
      reminders.value = await DatabaseHelper.allreminders();
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle errors, if any
      log("Error fetching reminders: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateReminderStatus(int id, bool newStatus) async {
    try {
      // Update reminder status in the database
      await DatabaseHelper.updateReminderStatus(id, newStatus);
      // Refresh reminders list
      await fetchReminders();
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle errors, if any
      log("Error updating reminder status: $e");
    }
  }
}
```

I need the user on the UI screen and the notification done when he is online the work manager updates that switch from true to false I hope I wrote my question clearly and thanks all in advance.